# Python: Condition for while loop doesnt terminate with Recursive function

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to implement a basic recursive function which should terminate once high parameter is no more greater than low parameter.

```
import time
def whileBlock(low, high):
    print("New low value:",low,"------","New high value:",high)
    while low < high:
        mid = (low + high)//2
        print("Low:",low,"Mid:",mid,"high:",high)
        time.sleep(2)

        whileBlock(low, mid)

whileBlock(0,10)
```

The middle value calculated is passed onto the recursive function. 
For the first 4 iterations, the code is running as expected. From 5th iteration onwards, though high is equal to 0 (same as low), while condition is not terminating and runs into a infinite loop.

Im not able to understand as to why the while loop is still getting high as 1 while the print statement above the condition shows high to be 0.

Code output

```
whileBlock(0,10)
New low value: 0 ------ New high value: 10
Low: 0 Mid: 5 high: 10
New low value: 0 ------ New high value: 5
Low: 0 Mid: 2 high: 5
New low value: 0 ------ New high value: 2
Low: 0 Mid: 1 high: 2
New low value: 0 ------ New high value: 1
Low: 0 Mid: 0 high: 1
New low value: 0 ------ New high value: 0
Low: 0 Mid: 0 high: 1
New low value: 0 ------ New high value: 0
Low: 0 Mid: 0 high: 1
New low value: 0 ------ New high value: 0
Low: 0 Mid: 0 high: 1
New low value: 0 ------ New high value: 0
Low: 0 Mid: 0 high: 1
```

Comment: Use `if low < hi`

Comment: Using recursion generally means you can avoid using a while loop. You implement a check like Primusa mentioned, and then your function will continuously recurse (acting LIKE a while loop) until that condition is met.

Comment: Thank you. If condition did the trick. But any reason why the while condition isnt terminating for the condition>

Comment: You aren't changing the value of low or high. If the code gets into the while loop, the variables in the conditional check never change so you never exit.

Comment: Yes. Because you don't update the local values. In your while version, the function recurses until it never enters the while loop. Imagine each recursive function call as a frame. Then one frame above the function that returned, `low` is STILL less than `high`, so it will continue the while loop. Which updates `mid`, prints your message, and then calls `whileBlock` again. The "new values" message will print, but `low` and `high` are 0 now so you don't enter the while loop. Function returns up one frame and we're back in the loop where `low == 0` and `high == 1`.. this continues forever.

Comment: @SyntaxVoid: Thank you for that clear explanation.